# $|z^i|<e^\pi,\;\;\forall z\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Good morning people ...

Do you have any idea to help me prove that $$|z^i|<e^{\pi}$$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

I tried to do $z^i=e^{i\ln z}=e^{i(\ln r+i\theta+2k\pi i)}$ if $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $$z^i=e^{i\ln r}\cdot e^{-(\theta+2k\pi)}\Longrightarrow |z^i|=|e^{i\ln r}\cdot e^{-(\theta+2k\pi)}|$$

Hence from this can not continue ...

Comment: $\lvert e^{i\ln r}\rvert=1$. However you need to take the principal value $k=0$ to arrive at $\lvert z^i\rvert < e^\pi$.

Comment: @kennytm From this, I have to $|z^i|<e^{-\theta}$, took me a while to see that $|z^{i\ln r}|=1$, but as use $|z^i|<e^{-\theta}$ to arrive in $|z^i|<e^\pi$? In the case $e^{-\theta}<e^\pi$?

Comment: $e^{-\theta}$ is a strictly decreasing function in $\theta$, and $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @kennytm I understand, thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is almost there. But first it seems the question assumes we only take the principal value of $z^i$, which requires $k=0$.

$$ \lvert z^i\rvert = \lvert e^{i\ln r} \cdot e^{-\theta} \rvert $$

Now note that $\ln r$ is real and thus $\lvert e^{i\ln r}\rvert=1$, and $e^{-\theta}$ is positive and strictly decreasing, so $\lvert z^i\rvert$ attains the maximum when $\theta$ is minimal, i.e. $\theta=-\pi$.

The inequality is false if we don't restrict to $k=0$ or $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$.